# capture joystick extra buttons

Tags: delphi, joystick

Could someone please tell me if there is  a way to capture extra joystick buttons? I mean buttons number 5,6,7,8 and so on.

I use this code to capture button down event :

```
procedure MMJOY1BUTTONDOWN (var LocMessage: TMMJoyStick); message MM_JOy1BUTTONDOWN;
```

But the problem is that it just captures the 4 standard buttons, not any extra buttons.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Multimedia Joystick API does not support generating window messages for buttons 5+, you have to poll their status manually using `joyGetPosEx()`.  Otherwise, you should use [DirectInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416842.aspx) from the DirectX API instead, as it replaces the older API.

**Update:** Alternatively, you can use the [Raw Input API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) to receive event notifications directly from the joystick hardware. See CodeProject for more details:

[Using the Raw Input API to Process Joystick Input](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185522/Using-the-Raw-Input-API-to-Process-Joystick-Input)